# Durandal+Knockout to develop a Single Page Application: Selectively show portions of page based upon authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, durandal

I am using Durandal, knockout to create a Single Page Application. I need to do following (two pretty simple things):

1. Show/hide widgets that are only for administrator, based upon the user's authorization,
2. Change menu options based upon whether user is authenticated or not (for anonymous show - login/sign up and when authenticated show "Welcome .." .

If this was a regular MVC4 application I would have done it using 
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { ... } check in razor views, but with views in durandal this is ruled out.

I want to avoid putting sensitive business logic in javascript - user need not know what kind of options could have been available to him if he was an administrator.

What's the best way to achieve this in Durandal & Knockout? I have been coding so far using classic ASP.NET and lately using ASP.NET MVC. Developing SPA using Durandal is a new game for me...If anyone can give me only steps/pointers to do this that will help a lot too..thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do it.

1. My menus are build inside a menubar.js file. The menuItems are observableArrays([]) initially and I subscribe to a topic "user-logged-in".
2. When the user logs in, I get the user's permissions/roles and store them locally in storage. and then send out notification "user-logged-in" with the user data.
3. My menubar recieves the notification, checks the permissions/roles and adds various menu items appropriately.
4. the shell.html has a view composition for the menubar.js. So if there are menuitems, it shows up, else it does not. so when the user logs in, the menuItems are populated and at this point the menu items show up.
5. When the user logs out, I clear the local storage cache and send out a message "user-logged-out".
6. The menubar.js recieves this message and clears it's menu items, essentially clearing the menu on the menubar.htm

You can essentially do the same for the widgets and use a visible binding to a property which hides or shows for a particular permission/role.

Also important is router.guardRoute. read up on this so that people cannot directly go to a route without logging in.

Hope that helps

Comment: just to add, I use amplify for my pub/sub

Comment: thanks a lot Sujesh..! one question - Does your menubar.js define all menus...even those which are supposed to be shown to administrator?

Comment: Well, my scenario is slightly different. I also bring in some of the menu items from the server based on specific inputs from the client. (mode for example). But most of the links are in place in the script itself and I load the extra ones from the server if need be.

Comment: Just to add, menu items are not that worrisome for me, because the data from my services are returned for specific roles and permissions. So it is like a double check. So even if someone let's say modifies or tries to directly access a link, my server will return back a :401: unauthorized, I catch that centrally and then route the user back to the login screen by clearing all the cache. that way it is secure.